# Wrap image in anchor of previous element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering whether it's possible to wrap an image in an anchor and give it the same `href` location as the link before it?

I've made a fiddle to explain what I'm on about. I basically want my image to take the link of the element before it when the page loads..
http://jsfiddle.net/ZJczA/

Comment: Please take greater care over your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the image has an `id` of `test_img`:

```
var a = $("#test_img").parent();
a.attr("href", a.prev().attr("href"));
```

To perform this operation for each image in the document, use something like this:

```
$("img").each(function() {
    var a = $(this).parent();
    a.attr("href", a.prev().attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, theres going to be a lot of links on the page, would this still work?

Comment: Ive tried adding .each to the script but still cant get it too work... http://jsfiddle.net/ZJczA/5/

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there are only two links on the page:

```
$('a').eq(1).attr('href',$('a').eq(0).attr('href'))
```

Comment: Theres going to be a lot of links on the page followed by an image, is there still a possibility of doing something like this? sorry for my naivity!